# WebView can load a website in the background?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a `webview` not attached to my `activity`, and i did a `loadUrl` on it. The `webview` only takes 1-2 seconds to load the website, but if I attach the `webview` to the layout of my `activity` after 10-20 seconds, I can see a empty black `webview` for 1 or 2 seconds before the loaded website is displayed. I can't understand why.

Why is the website not being displayed instantly if it is loaded in the background?

```
adWebView = new WebView(activity);
adWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
adWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
adWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
adWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
adWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
adWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Does it do that for all websites?

Comment: yes, it is the same problem in all websites

Comment: That isn't normal behavior, could you post some code?

Comment: I would try loading without the page without changes to the settings first. After that I would double check to see if you aren't doing something else on the UI thread.

Comment: i need all those settings, also the UI is not doing anything more

Answer (score 0):

That's because WebView doesn't do layout unless it is attached. And laying out an HTML page is not instant.

If you want to pre-render offscreen, attach WebView, but put it outside of the visible area first. You can also use `ViewPager` class if you need to swipe between WebViews.